# LLDB alias for multiple commands as one

Tags: xcode, macos, debugging, lldb

I am trying to debug a library whose source I don't have, so I'm using LLDB disassembly a lot.        I was wondering if there was a way to automatically run disassemble after every call to 'thread step-in.' Currently, when I do 'thread step-in,' LLDB executes the instruction, and then returns with a blank prompt. To see, where the EIP moved to, I need to type disassemble after every thread step-in, which is extremely distracting and annoying (also, LLDB doesn't seem to end expressions with ';' so putting multiple commands on one line doesn't work.)

More generally, I was wondering if there is a way to create an alias for multiple LLDB commands in succession: For example a single alias that could print the contents of %rdi, then disassemble 10 lines around EIP. (Yes, I could write python script for it, but I don't have that much time on my hand :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the correct way to do this is via the Python scripting interface.  There was a deliberate decision to avoid gdb's approach of cramming enough flow-control and execution logic in the debugger's command language to make this possible (or rather -- to make it possible... poorly).  Instead of that approach, there is a low barrier where you need to use Python to accomplish a task -- but the full power of the debugger is available through some pretty easy-to-use interfaces in Python.  lldb leaves the scripting language to Python and concentrates on providing a clean and powerful API that is easy to use from Python.

But to address your goal here, why won't the `stop-disassembly-count` setting do what you need?  In fact, it should already be doing what you want unless you've disabled disassembly display in your `~/.lldbinit` file by changing the default setting of `stop-disassembly-display`.

```
(lldb) settings show stop-disassembly-count
stop-disassembly-count (int) = 4
(lldb) settings show stop-disassembly-display
stop-disassembly-display (enum) = no-source
(lldb)
```

lldb's default behavior is to show *some* kind of context when you are stepping through a program.  If source code is available, it will show the source you're stepping through.  If no source, it will show the assembly instructions that are about to be executed.  There is a little bug when you have debug information (so the debugger knows file and line numbers) but the source code is unavailable (or at a different path) -- right now lldb will show you disassembly but that is not the correct behavior for this case.  Users are still operating at a source level (using `s` and `n` to step, instead of `si` and `ni` for instruction-level stepping) and lldb should show no context in this instance, just displaying the source file name and line number.

Comment: Okay the issue was with the lldbinit file on the machine was debugging. Really love LLDB. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to create a super simple alias that combines one or two basic commands I've found the following is *almost* reasonable as a one-liner

```
command alias ff script lldb.debugger.HandleCommand('frame info'); lldb.debugger.HandleCommand('disassemble')
```

It's a little cumbersome and doesn't work in all cases, but it does at least let you combine a couple of commands in-place without having to create and switch context to a separate file.

Otherwise as @JasonMolenda explains the more general approach is to write a Python function, which is straightforward and lets you take full advantage of LLDB's great Python support.  Nevertheless, sometimes it's still nice to be able to define in-line and a one-liner trumps even the low-bar of a Python script.

---

As an aside, LLDB does have support for defining a list of LLDB commands in-place for e.g. execution at a breakpoint

```
> breakpoint command add 1    # Execute the following on breakpoint 1
p x
p y
p z
DONE
```

but I don't believe the same facility applies to defining new commands unless I can be corrected.